# apache camel route choice/filter from property file

Tags: xml, spring, apache-camel

I am configuring an apache-camel route who looks like this:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="file:/../jboss/dependencies-fuse/archivo.properties"/>
        <route>
            <from uri="amqLocal:endpointA"/>
            <choice>
                <when>
                    <simple>{{property.var}} == 'F' </simple>
                    <to uri="amqLocal:endpointB"/>
                </when>
            </choice>
            <to uri="amqLocal:endpointC"/>
            <to uri="amqLocal:endpointD"/>   
        </route> 
</camelContext>
```

supposing the properties file is well defined, I'm looking for a way that my router can deliver messages to the endpoint called amqLocal:endpointB, only when the property called property.var is equal to 'F'.
Then the router should continue throwing the same message to endpoints amqLocal:endpointC and amqLocal:endpointD.

I don't know if it works like I said. Maybe I should use the `<filter>` component but it is always throwing the follow exception:

```
org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[JmsMessage[JmsMessageID: ID:emi-pc-38668-1459998422949-1:2:1:1:1]]
  at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1635)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
  at org.apache.camel.builder.SimpleBuilder.createPredicate(SimpleBuilder.java:93)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
  at org.apache.camel.builder.SimpleBuilder.matches(SimpleBuilder.java:74)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:92)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
  at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621084 com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashma
```

Can anyone help? Is there another good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{{var}}` instead as `{{ }}` is the properties placeholder syntax: http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

If you want to refer to the property placeholder using the simple language, you need to use the `${ }` syntax, and use the `properties-location` function: http://camel.apache.org/simple

So that would be `${properties-location:var}`. When using this then the placeholder is resolved for each message at runtime. Where as the former is resolved once during startup of Camel.

Comment: Hi Claus, thx for your quickly answer. The way you say is indeed the way i'm using.

Comment: Hi Claus, thx for your quickly answer. The way you say is indeed the way i'm using, cause what you called "var" is my "property.var" defined property.
For example, this works fine:

 <log message=" {{property.var}} - IT WORKS "/>

but when i try to use this 
<simple>{{property.var}} == 'F' </simple>
it fails.

could be that this is not the appropriate use of the <choice>. i mean, given tho the <choice> only a one <when> ?

Comment: Claus thanks a lot. The solution was adding properties-location
<choice>
                <when>
                    <simple>${properties-location:property.var.} == 'F'</simple>
              .....
....